# Any nice looking or "WOW" effect looking for HTML select

Tags: javascript, css

Previously, I am using

```
<select size="8">
<option>Item 1</option>
<option>Item 2</option>
<option>Item 3</option>
<option>Item 4</option>
<option>Item 5</option>
<option>Item 6</option>
<option>Item 7</option>
<option>Item 8</option>
<option>Item 9</option>
</select>
```

provide a JList box liked place, to hold a collections of item, to let user have a simple view to browse about items.

However, the look of this kind of pure HTML element doesn't look shinning.

Have anyone of you come across any similar widget/ JavaScript library/ CSS template ...
which will make this List Box look great?

Thanks

p/s List Box is something look like this 
[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/14ListDialog-nowrap.png))</sub>

Comment: Not sure stackoverflow is the place for design suggestions...

Comment: But perhaps, once you know what you're after, http://doctype.com might be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style it with CSS.  [Here's an example.](http://home.tiscali.nl/developerscorner/fdc-varia/styling-dropdown-boxes.htm)

Here's [another with more "WOW"](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)

Comment: That is WOW. But I think we have some misunderstanding the word "List Box". I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Some places to turn for inspiration:

- [Pattern Tap](http://www.patterntap.com)
- [Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/)
- [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Google for "Jquery SelectBox ", you may get some results.

Here is one, which you can use as an enhancement of select box

http://www.brainfault.com/2007/07/23/select-box-replacement/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jqtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) for a complete form redesign ..